# Calculating totals in SQL stored procedure from rows from same table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to build a stored procedure that will allow me to subtract a value based on a specific condition from another value based on another condition but my problem is that all rows reside in the same table. It's probably easier to show you what I mean.

Imagine if you have the following table (kept simple for simplicity sake)

```
ID    Name     Total    Date
1     User1    5        20111106
2     User2    6        20111106
3     User3    7        20111105
4     User1    8        20111106
5     User3    4        20111117
6     User1    4        20111117
7     User5    1        20111105
8     User1    9        20111105
9     User3    5        20111106
10    User1    3        20111117
```

First I want to sum the total by date just for user1 and group by date

```
Total     Date
9        20111105
13       20111106
7        20111117
```

Next I want to sum the total by date for all other users excluding user1 and group by date

```
Total     Date
8         20111105
11        20111106
4         20111117
```

and finally I somehow want my stored procedure to take the above data and give me the following. I want to subtract the total obtained from "User1" from the total obtained from all other users but using the date as the matching parameter.

and the final result would be as follows:

```
Total     Date
-1        20111105
-2        20111106
-3        20111117
```

Is this making sense???

Thanks.

T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
with User1Totals as 
(
  select [Name], sum(Total) as Total, [Date]
  from YourTable
  where [Name] = 'User1'
  group by [Name], [Date]
), 
OtherUsersTotals as
(
  select sum(Total) as Total, [Date]
  from YourTable
  where [Name] <> 'User1'
  group by [Date]
)

select isnull(t2.Total, 0) - isnull(t1.Total, 0), coalesce(t2.[Date], t1.[Date])
from User1Totals t1
full outer join OtherUsersTotals t2 on t1.[Date] = t2.[Date]
​
```

This handles the scenarios in your sample data, as well as two other scenarios - 1) when User1 has an entry on a day that other users do not, and 2) when other users have data on a day that User1 does not.

Working example here - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120224/

Comment: Thanks for that! This is exactly what I needed. Never seen the data.stackexchange before.... Excellent... Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work...

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(20)
SET @Name='User1'
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN Name=@Name THEN Total*-1
            ELSE Total
        END
    ) [Total Adj]
    ,Date
FROM Table
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: I'll give that a try... If it works, it certainly is a cleaner solution than what I was about to post. I ended up creating 2 temp tables and then doing a simple join and that worked..

Comment: Worked a charm but one small problem ... I think it's excluding values that are null... For example on a specific day, User1 may not have had any records on a specific day but User2 may have.. This should ideally display the Total just for user2. Using the temp table scenario handles that.

Comment: +1 This will also display a date total if just user2 had totals.

Comment: I'm not following how my SQL could have excluded anything. I am not specifying the user in the where clause at all. Can you please elaborate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by creating temp tables.

**Step # 01:**
Create a temp1 table and bring your first required result for only user 1 in it.

```
CREATE TABLE Temp1
(
ID IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
Total int,
Date datetime)

insert into Temp1(Total , Date)
values (select sum(Total) as Total , Date where Name = 'user1' group by Date order by Date asc)
```

**Step # 02:**
Create a temp2 table and fill it with other user inforamtion.

```
CREATE TABLE Temp2
(
ID IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
Total int,
Date datetime)

insert into Temp1(Total , Date)
values (select sum(Total) as Total , Date where Name is not 'user1' group by Date
```

order by Date asc)

**Step # 03:**
Now subtract records and drop temp tables.

```
select (t2.Total - t1.Total) as Total , Date  from temp2 t2
inner join temp1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID;

drop table temp1;
drop table temp2;
```

Comment: Hey Syeda, this is exactly how I went about it after posting this question but thanks.